# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter]

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to write an app that takes twitter search stream. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-      instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
<groupId>co.edureka</groupId>  
<artifactId>Spring_Integration_Module_Examples</artifactId>  
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>  
<dependencies>  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>  
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>  

  <dependency>  
 <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>  
 <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>  
 <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>  
 </dependency> 

  <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>  
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>  
  </dependency>  
</dependencies>  
</project>
```

I also have the following si-components configuration code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xmlns:int-twitter="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter"
xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter/spring-integration-twitter.xsd">

<int-twitter:search-inbound-channel-adapter
    query="#springintegration" channel="inboundTweets">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="3" />
</int-twitter:search-inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transformer input-channel="inboundTweets"
    output-channel="tweetsText" expression="payload.getText()" />

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="tweetsText" 
id="consumer-file-adapter" 
directory="file:C:\\Users\\sagio\\Documents\\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\\tweeterStream\\data" />

<bean id="twitterTemplate" class="org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterTemplate">
    <constructor-arg value=.... />
    <constructor-arg value=.... />
    <constructor-arg value=.... />
    <constructor-arg value=.... />
</bean>

<int:channel id="inboundTweets" />
<int:channel id="tweetsText" />
</beans>
```

When I try to run it I get the following exception:
***Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter]***

What is the right configuration for this problem?

Comment: You don't have the `spring-integration-twitter` dependency. Whilst adding that I would strongly suggest moving to the 4.x branch of Spring Integration as that supports Spring 4 better.

Answer (score 1):

In your list of dependencies you are missing the [`spring-integration-twitter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-twitter/src) dependency.

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>  
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>
```

I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of Spring Integration as that uses the Spring 4.x features better then the 3.x branch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-      instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>co.edureka</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_Integration_Module_Examples</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-integration.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring-integration.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-twitter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The `spring-core` and `spring-beans` dependency are already included when adding the `spring-context` dependency.

Or even better you might want to use the [Spring IO Platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) to align all the versions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-      instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>co.edureka</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_Integration_Module_Examples</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```